# prevent Mail from checking for mail if VPN is down

Tags: email, vpn

My employer insists on using a VPN when people access email via Exchange. Is there any way to prevent Mail from checking for mail if the VPN is down?

Comment: Apart from not launching Mail or not having it open all the time, I would be very surprised if there was a way. Oh, and of course setting the check interval to Manual.

Comment: Old question - but no accepted answer. Ever find a solution, or workaround? I am having the same issue...

Comment: No, I did not find a workaround that you would like. Workaround #1: Use Outlook client for the Mac. Turns out that the employer's firewall is misconfigured and you don't need the VPN up to check mail with it.  Workaround #2: Start Mail after you bring up the VPN.

Comment: You'e right - thanks for the comment. For me, Outlook acts in the same manner as Mail.app. If I'm not on the VPN, it prompts me for my password. My employer (a large University) does not want Email access when not on the VPN, but perhaps I'll inquire to see if anything can be done at that end to provide a more informative failure...

Answer (score 1):

Have your employer block access to the IMAP server from non VPN connections. That way Mail can check all it likes but it won't get anywhere. As long as Mail is using a secure connection for the IMAP server it will reject most any nefarious attempt to hijack the attempted connection.

Comment: Now that I think about you having to ask this question I'm more confused. What is the purpose of requiring you to use a VPN for IMAP other than to stop the IMAP server from being exposed directly to the broader internet? Maybe just take the time to explain to your explorer that a secured IMAP connection is just as secure as a VPN connection.

Comment: The Exchange server is a shared Exchange server (Office 365). Our employer has set up an firewall rule that causes authentication to fail if the IP address is not coming from the VPN range. This is because the employer uses two-factor authentication, which Exchange authentication does not support.

Comment: So then why do you care if Mail keeps checking for mail and failing to connect while the VPN is down? Once it's back up it should automatically reconnect. Is the reconnection not happening?

Comment: I care because the modal pop-up message asking for a password is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do it for a single application, but what you're looking for a is a [killswitch](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=vpn+killswitch+mac). I don't know what software you're using so it's a little hard to help you further, but if you post that info, I'll gladly. help.

Comment: No, I really don't want a killswitch. I just want Mail to not check mail when the VPN isn't up because I'm sick of seeing "cannot connect" errors. The same applies for AddressBook and Calendar.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Not sure what I can do to help you there then.